# API Gateway cache not working

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

How to enable proper caching for an API Gateway endpoint?

I've enabled the API cache (see screenshot), but when I request the URL, the response time stayed the same as before.

I tried enabling the API cache option:

[image: Cache option]

And configured the Cache-Control header:

[image: Cache-Control header]

And also enabled caching by a query parameter:

[image: Query param cache]

Comment: What is your integration backend? Do you have the capability to look at logs to see whether or not your backend has been called when caching should occur?

Comment: The backend is a Lambda.

Answer (score 14):

Caching in API Gateway is not implemented via CloudFront. API Gateway creates a CloudFront distribution on your behalf when you create your API, but caching is actually implemented via use of dedicated caching infrastructure. Even with caching enabled you will continue to see "cache miss" headers from CloudFront.

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for the correction. So are you saying that `X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront` is not an indicator of cache not working?

Comment: @katspaugh Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: The thing is, the response time also seems to be the same with or without API cache enabled. I guess I need to rephrase the question.

Comment: @katspaugh how long does your integration take to run? API Gateway does incur some overhead.

Comment: @BobKinney So how does someone confirm a response is pulled from the API Gateway cache?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson This is logged in CloudWatch, but currently no indication is included in the response.

Answer (score 8):

I found the AWS forum provided some more insight, incase it helps anyone else.

> API Gateway integrates with CloudFront behind the scenes. We
> automatically create a global CloudFront distribution for your APIs in
> order to reduce the latency perceived by end users. However, the API
> Gateway cache is handled in the region where API Gateway runs and your
> API is deployed. Requests are accepted by the CloudFront PoP and then
> sent to the API Gateway in its origin region, that's where API Gateway
> will check against its cache and return a cached response if possible.
> At the moment API Gateway does not use CloudFront's cache at the edge.